# Query And Get Data from Google Analytic

Tags: api, google-analytics

I want to retrieve data from google analytics, by its [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data

?ids=ga:12345

&dimensions=ga:source,ga:medium

&metrics=ga:visits,ga:bounces

&sort=-ga:visits

&filters=ga:medium%3D%3Dreferral

&segment=gaid::10 OR dynamic::ga:medium%3D%3Dreferral

&start-date=2008-10-01

&end-date=2008-10-31

&start-index=10

&max-results=100

&prettyprint=true
```

but i can't find my **?ids=**. Can you help me finding it and give an example query string if any please.

Comment: please, write the reason for closing.

Comment: Not sure why it was closed. I saw it as a legitimate question. Glad I could answer before it was closed. Maybe it was because of the tags that you used. Should have stick to google-analytics only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Google Analytics Front End
2. Click on Admin (top right)
3. Click on the Profile that you want to query through the API
4. Go to Profile Settings Tab
5. Copy the Profile Id number. it should be something like 123456789
6. Prepend `ga:` to it. So it becomes `ga:123456789`
7. Query the API with it.
8. ...
9. Profit!

Comment: Great Helo and check this too.https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/